# C# Sqlite EntityFramework - create table and load data in one step

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

In C# I have a project that creates a table in the database, then inserts data. And that works ok. Then I want to load data to entity framework and I get error The entity type Jobs is not part of the model for the current context.
But when I create a table, insert data then turn off the application and then turn on and load data it works ok.
This is my code:

```
using (DatabaseSqliteContext context = new DatabaseSqliteContext())
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(" DROP TABLE JobsImp ");

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE TABLE 'JobsImp' ( "
        + " Id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
        + " Title         VARCHAR(1000) NULL ); ");
}

using (DatabaseSqliteContext context = new DatabaseSqliteContext())
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO JobsImp (Id, Title) SELECT job_id, title FROM jobs");        
}


using (DatabaseSqliteContext context = new DatabaseSqliteContext())
{
    var aaaa = context.Jobs.ToList(); // error The entity type Jobs is not part of the model for the current context.         
}
```

How to refresh an entity after creating the table, because it doesn't know that the table has been created. It knows about that after reboot application.

Comment: Have you tried not using the "using" statement to preserve the context variable in the code block?

Comment: Yes I have tried, at the begin I have entire code in one context, but the result was the same

Comment: Even when I have tree usings, OnModelCreating is called only one, at the beginn. I think that this is problem because in this method configuration to table is loaded and when it is called at the begin, the table doesn't exist

Comment: Maybe refreshing your context is the way. Can you try this code for me.


public void RefreshDatabase(TEntity entity)
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Context)
        .ObjectContext
        .Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity);
}

please tell what happens.

Comment: I have do like this: public void RefreshDatabase(IEnumerable<Jobs> entity)
        {
            ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity);
        }
But I've got similar error An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Hmmm. I see. Can you revert your code back to normal where you don't use the using statements to preserve the context variable? And then add this code. But I am also suspecting that the casting to IObjectContextAdapter makes it null. Maybe you can debug and see if inside the RefreshDatabase method the entity object is not null and this is not null as well?

Comment: The context isn't null. The Jobs collection is null. I've reverted code and result is the same. The dbset<jobs> is not connected to the new table, just created